# IBM TSM 7.1 reclamation not working on primary pool

Tags: backup, tivoli

I'm having a problem on IBM TSM 7.1 my test enviroment with primary pool space reclamation.

while there are multiple volumes with reclaimable space i allways get this error:

```
tsm: SERVER1>reclaim stg stgnasdisk thr=60 dura=60 wait=yes
ANR2111W RECLAIM STGPOOL: There is no data to process for STGNASDISK.
ANS8001I Return code 11.
```

Q vol snippet:

```
E:\DATA\V306237716.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    1.0    Full
E:\DATA\V306237717.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    2.0    Full
E:\DATA\V306237718.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    0.5    Full
E:\DATA\V306237719.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         4.9 G   91.3    Full
E:\DATA\V306237720.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G   75.9    Full
E:\DATA\V306237721.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    3.0    Full
E:\DATA\V306237722.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    0.5    Full
E:\DATA\V306237723.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G   16.9    Full
E:\DATA\V306237724.BFS    STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G    0.3    Full
E:\DATA\V34160080.BFS     STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         4.9 G   19.5    Full
E:\DATA\V34160081.BFS     STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G   75.9    Full
E:\DATA\V34160082.BFS     STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         4.9 G   49.1    Full
E:\DATA\V34160083.BFS     STGNASDISK   PRIMARY         5.0 G   81.6    Full
```

Volume shows 99% reclaimable space, still nothing happens:

```
tsm: SERVER1>q vol E:\DATA\V306237716.BFS f=d

              Volume Name: E:\DATA\V306237716.BFS
        Storage Pool Name: STGNASDISK
        Device Class Name: PRIMARY
       Estimated Capacity: 5.0 G
  Scaled Capacity Applied:
                 Pct Util: 1.0
            Volume Status: Full
                   Access: Read/Write
   Pct. Reclaimable Space: 99.0
          Scratch Volume?: No
          In Error State?: No
 Number of Writable Sides: 1
  Number of Times Mounted: 6
        Write Pass Number: 1
Approx. Date Last Written: 07/24/2015 12:16:54
   Approx. Date Last Read: 08/14/2015 09:33:45
      Date Became Pending:
   Number of Write Errors: 0
    Number of Read Errors: 0
          Volume Location:
Volume is MVS Lanfree Capable : No
Last Update by (administrator): SERVER_CONSOLE
    Last Update Date/Time: 07/24/2015 12:10:04
     Begin Reclaim Period:
       End Reclaim Period:
```

Drive Encryption Key Manager:
      Logical Block Protected: No

Copy pool reclaims work fine.  Storage pool detailed overview:

tsm: SERVER1>q stg stgnasdisk f=d

```
                Storage Pool Name: STGNASDISK
                Storage Pool Type: Primary
                Device Class Name: PRIMARY
               Estimated Capacity: 558 G
               Space Trigger Util: 38.4
                         Pct Util: 35.7
                         Pct Migr: 35.7
                      Pct Logical: 49.1
                     High Mig Pct: 90
                      Low Mig Pct: 70
                  Migration Delay: 0
               Migration Continue: Yes
              Migration Processes: 1
            Reclamation Processes: 1
                Next Storage Pool:
             Reclaim Storage Pool:
           Maximum Size Threshold: No Limit
                           Access: Read/Write
                      Description:
                Overflow Location:
            Cache Migrated Files?:
                       Collocate?: Group
            Reclamation Threshold: 100
        Offsite Reclamation Limit:
  Maximum Scratch Volumes Allowed: 25
   Number of Scratch Volumes Used: 1
    Delay Period for Volume Reuse: 0 Day(s)
           Migration in Progress?: No
             Amount Migrated (MB): 0.00
 Elapsed Migration Time (seconds): 0
         Reclamation in Progress?: No
   Last Update by (administrator): JEF
            Last Update Date/Time: 08/20/2015 17:46:49
         Storage Pool Data Format: Native
             Copy Storage Pool(s):
              Active Data Pool(s):
          Continue Copy on Error?: Yes
                         CRC Data: No
                 Reclamation Type: Threshold
      Overwrite Data when Deleted:
                Deduplicate Data?: Yes
 Processes For Identifying Duplicates: 1
        Duplicate Data Not Stored: 0  (0%)
                   Auto-copy Mode: Client
Contains Data Deduplicated by Client?: No
     Deduplicate Requires Backup?:
```

The reclaim threshold on 100% is normal, this is to prevent reclamation during backup. Reclamation is started daily in the maintanence scipt.

Any help on this is very welcome. I have searched the net but did not really find anything that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked IBM about this issue. TSM needs at least 1 pool without deduplication otherwise it will never reclaim the primary dedup pool even when the data is expired.

On the test envirement i had both the primary and copy pool on deduplication.

I created a non dedup copy pool and reclaims now work normal.